# What are the dimensionality requirements for np.dot?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable `W` that has:

```
[[1.]
 [2.]
 [3.]
 [4.]
 [5.]]
```

And another variable `X` that has:

```
[[1.  5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [1.  4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [1.  4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [1.  4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [1.  5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]
 [1.  5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4]
 [1.  4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3]
 [1.  5.  3.4 1.5 0.2]
 [1.  4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2]
 [1.  4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1]
 [1.  5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2]
 ...
 [1.  5.7 2.8 4.1 1.3]]
```

I keep guessing and checking to see how to `np.dot` them together. `np.dot(W.T, X.T)` seems to work, but the shape is wrong: `(1, 100)`.

What I want to do is multiply like:

`1 * 1 + 2 * 5.1 + 3 * 3.5 + 4 * 1.4 + 5 * 0.02` for each row in `X`. How can I do that?

Comment: If `(1, 100)` is the wrong shape, what's the right one? What do you want?

Comment: The shape I want is `(100, 1)`

Comment: Do you know linear algebra? For 2D input, `numpy.dot` is matrix multiplication. The shape requirements for 2D input are exactly the requirements for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Reading the documentation of np.dot would help you greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is *row by column*:

```
        X
XXXXX   X   .
..... * X = .
.....   X   .
        X
```

So:

```
In [6]: a=np.array([[1,  5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
   ...:  [1,  4.9, 3,  1.4, 0.2],
   ...:  [1,  4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
   ...:  [1,  4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
   ...:  [1,  5,  3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
   ...:  [1,  5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
   ...:  [1,  4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
   ...:  [1,  5,  3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
   ...:  [1,  4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2],
   ...:  [1,  4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1],
   ...:  [1,  5.4, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2]])

In [8]: b=np.array([[1.],
   ...:  [2.],
   ...:  [3.],
   ...:  [4.],
   ...:  [5.]])

In [25]: np.dot(a,b)
Out[25]:
array([[28.3],
       [26.4],
       [26.2],
       [26.5],
       [28.4],
       [32.3],
       [27.5],
       [28.2],
       [25.1],
       [26.6],
       [29.9]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The last dimension of **a** should be the same size of the second-to-last dimension of **b**.

Given: `np.dot(a, b)`

More references: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

```
W = np.array([[1.],[2.],[3.],[4.],[5.]])

X = np.array([[1.,  5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
              [1.,  4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
              [1. , 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
              [1.  ,4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
              [1.  ,5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
              [1.  ,5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4]])

np.matmul(X,W)

array([[28.3],
       [26.4],
       [26.2],
       [26.5],
       [28.4],
       [32.3]])
```

Quick check on the output:

```
1*1 + 2*5.1 + 3*3.5 + 4*1.4 + 5*0.2 = 28.3
```

Note that in this case it is equivalent to `np.dot` given that both inputs are `2-D arrays`.